# Is normal to have so many vulnerabilities in a Vue 2 brand new project?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I created a new project via

```sh
vue create <project-name>
```

and I get this warning:

> 74 vulnerabilities (2 low, 59 moderate, 13 high)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:   npm audit
> fix --force

I ran
`npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` and it makes no difference.

I am new to web development, is it normal to have this many vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of JavaScript. This is legit and is mainly coming from the fact that the ecosystem is moving quickly.

Also, not all dependencies can always be upgraded to the latest (safest ones) if there are breaking changes (meaning that you need specific packages to be within a specific range to be used together).

Now, is it something that you need to worry about? Probably not since even the "high" vulnerabilities are not that critical (usually) and **very** specific cases. You could check the details but usually, you don't need to worry about it.

Also, the world of IT (and per-se the Web), is some huge cheese with a lot of holes. Don't bother trying to fix those and enjoy your development journey. Especially since your server or even human factor is still the weakest link anyway.