# Should I be concerned about NPM vulnerabilities when using Vue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

I just installed `@Vue-cli` and I decided to create my first project using `Vue3`.
After running `vue create hello-world` and it finished building the project, the cli said
`7 moderate severity vulnerabilities`

How bad are these? `moderate` is very subjective. I tried running `npm audit fix --force` which instead said
`28 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 12 high)`.

Is this just one of the things you should just accept and hope that no one exploits the vulnerabilities?

After running npm audit it said this

```
# npm audit report

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1
Severity: moderate
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @vue/cli-service@4.5.17, which is a breaking change
node_modules/log-update/node_modules/ansi-regex
  strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex
  node_modules/log-update/node_modules/strip-ansi
    string-width  2.1.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/log-update/node_modules/string-width
      wrap-ansi  3.0.0 - 6.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of string-width
      Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
      node_modules/log-update/node_modules/wrap-ansi
        log-update  2.1.0 - 3.4.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of wrap-ansi
        node_modules/log-update
          progress-webpack-plugin  *
          Depends on vulnerable versions of log-update
          node_modules/progress-webpack-plugin
            @vue/cli-service  >=5.0.0-alpha.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of progress-webpack-plugin
            node_modules/@vue/cli-service
```

Which to me looks like it all boils down to `Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex`.

What's the proper way of dealing with this? Just letting it be or is it as easy as updating a package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is normal to have so many vulnerabilities in a Vue 2 brand new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635064/is-normal-to-have-so-many-vulnerabilities-in-a-vue-2-brand-new-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of my other answer, I'll add that everything is hackable nowadays. Is it an issue per-se? Not really since you're not really launching rockets.

Is it spooky? Yeah maybe because of how it sounds but at the end, if somebody in your company opens a phishing email you're exposed, so yeah: live your life and don't worry too much about it.

Also, a as reminder: every package that you install can be malicious at some point and during various steps. If you want a 100% bullet-proof codebase, you'll need to write everything yourself from bottom to top.